# RXJS - merge two stream results into one sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs

I have two streams. Let's say:

```
const firstStream = Rx.of([
  {
    first: 'first',
  }, {
    third: 'third',

  }
]);

const secondStream = Rx.of([
  {
    second: 'second'
  }, {
    fourth: 'fourth'
  }
]);
```

Now I want a stream that combines the result of these two streams and maps the result array sorted as follows:

```
const resultArr = [
  {
    first: 'first',
  }, 
  {
    second: 'second'
  },
  {
    third: 'third',
  },
  {
    fourth: 'fourth'
  }
];
```

I tried to use `combineLatest` with RxJS `flatmap` operator, but that did not work out. I provided a stackblitz playground to test around: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ftxt7o)

I'm sure there are plenty of ways to do this. Maybe someone can help me out :)

Comment: Do those streams complete and after they complete you want their sorted result or you need the sorted results of the streams, each time any of those two streams emit value?

Comment: Those streams do complete and yes after completion I want the sorted result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const { from, merge } = rxjs;
const { reduce, map, mergeMap } = rxjs.operators

const a = from(['first', 'third']);
const b = from(['second', 'fourth']);


const sortMap = {
  first: 0,
  second: 1,
  third: 2,
  fourth: 4,
}

merge(a, b).pipe(
  // wait until every observable has completed,
  // zip all the values into an array
  reduce((res, item) => res.concat(item), []),
  
  // sort the array accordingly to your needs
  map(list => list.sort((a, b) => sortMap[a] - sortMap[b])),
  
  // flatten the array into a sequence
  mergeMap(list => list),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js" integrity="sha256-mNXCdYv896VtdKYTBWgurbyH+p9uDUgWE4sYjRnB5dM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Not on topic, but I like the way you showed the demo here, I had never thought about referring `rxjs` and creating a live demo in the snippet, thumbs up :)

Answer (score 1):

enter code hereAs you said your streams first complete and after that, you need the sorted value as single output of the stream, so I would recommend the `forkJoin` operator, which operator will `Wait for Observables to complete and then combine last values they emitted.`

```js
const { of, forkJoin } = rxjs;
const { map } = rxjs.operators;

let a$ = of([1, 8, 10, 4]);
let b$ = of([3, 5, 43, 0]);

forkJoin(a$, b$)
  .pipe(
    map(([a, b]) => [...a, ...b]),
    map(x => x.sort((a, b) => a - b))
  )
  .subscribe(x => {
    console.log('Sorted =>', x);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js" integrity="sha256-mNXCdYv896VtdKYTBWgurbyH+p9uDUgWE4sYjRnB5dM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```